# What is the definition of fornication and why?

Tags: bible, terminology

In technical terms, that have objective meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I quote the Oxford Concise Dictionary; "Voluntary sexual intercourse between man and unmarried woman" (with the note that the word is occasionally resticted to cases in which the man is also unmarried). The origin of the English word is the latin word FORNIX, meaning "a brothel", presumably because women outside brothels were traditionally less willing to take part. However, the word in general usage is not limited to brothels. In other words, it is used for sexual activity detached from the marriage relationship if the word "adultery" does not apply.

Comment: That would mean Mat 19:9 is a nonsense statement https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/mat/19/9/s_948011

Comment: If you want to ask about a discrepancy you see in a Bible verse, please ask another question specifically about that.

Comment: @Aseka Vena The word in the Greek of Matthew ch19 v9 is PORNEIA, which the RSV translates as "unchastity".

Comment: In MT 19:9, the noun "fornication" (πορνεια/porneia in codex 04 (C); πορνια/pornia in codices 01 (א) and W (032), and πορνειας/porneias in codices 03 (B) and 05 (D) is best defined as "harlotry (including adultery and incest); figuratively, idolatry" (Strong's G4202). πορνεια/porneia is from the Greek verb πορνευω/porneuō meaning "to act the harlot[; i.e.,] indulge in unlawful lust, or (fig.) to practice idolatry" (Strong's G4203).

Answer (score 0):

[Fornication has the usual meaning given to it in the English language:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fornication)

> the action of having sex with someone who you are not married to

It isn't a specifically Christian term.

Comment: That is incompatible with Mark 19:9 https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/mat/19/9/t_conc_948011

Comment: Mark 19:9 I meant. It wouldn't be logically possible for the verse to mean anything if that was the definition

Comment: There is no such verse as Mark 19:9. If you want to ask about a seeming discrepancy in a Bible verse, please ask another question.

Comment: Oh Matthew 19:9. don't know why these things trip me up every so often.

Comment: Either way, if you want to ask about that verse, please ask another question. And be detailed about what you see as the discrepancy.

Comment: @Aseka Vena The word in the greek of Matthew ch19 v9 is PORNEIA, which the RSV translates as "unchastity".